# Это приложение? Писать с дефисом?

Tags: приложение

Юрист-мошенник? Приложение ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‟Юрист-мошенник” пишется через дефис. Правило следующее: Если есть одиночные (состоящие из одного слова) приложение и определяемое слово без именных в паре, то дефис ставится всегда, кроме 4-х пунктов:

**1. ПЕРВОЕ СЛОВО ЗАМЕНЯЕТСЯ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ:**
Существительное, которое идет первым, заменяется прилагательным, как ‟малютка сын” заменяется ‟маленький сын”.
Сочетание юрист-мошенник не подходит под этот пункт.

**2. СОЧЕТАНИЯ СО СЛОВАМИ ГРАЖДАНИН, ГОСПОДИН, ТОВАРИЩ:**
Вот несколько примеров: ‟гражданин посол”, ‟товарищ майор”.
Сочетание юрист-мошенник не подходит под этот пункт.

**3. ПОЯСНЕНИЕ ИЗ ОДНОГО СЛОВА.**
Когда предложение прерывается, делается отступление с информацией из одного слов (данное правило про одиночные приложение и определяемое слово), и предложение продолжается, — все это с соответствующей интонацией отступления. Вот пример такого приложения: ‟Отца, пьяницу, кормила с малых лет, и сама себя”.
Сочетание юрист-мошенник не подходит под этот пункт.

**4. РОД-ВИД ОТНОШЕНИЯ И ПОДОБНЫЕ СОЧЕТАНИЯ, ГДЕ ЗА БОЛЕЕ ОБЩИМ СЛОВОМ А СЛЕДУЕТ РАСКРЫВАЮЩЕЕ А, МЕНЕЕ ОБЩЕЕ Б (СТАВИТСЯ НИЧЕГО ИЛИ ТИРЕ):**
Гриб лисичка, пожалуй, скоро попадет в Красную книгу.
Цветок мальва известен с древних времен.
Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину. (Тире, когда Б находится в конце предложение, является первостепенным для смысла, перед ним более длинная пауза.)
Не следует путать с научными терминами и терминами обозначающими специальность, которые всегда пишутся через дефис, как: жук-плавунец, рак-отшельник, слесарь-инструментальщик, химик-органик.
Сочетание юрист-мошенник не подходит под этот пункт.